# Transporte De Imagens Usando o Modulo Request Do NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagem, request

Eu tenho um codigo que faz uma request para um site é entrega para o usuarío Mas ele não consegue enviar Imagens A Imagem Não Carrega(Quando eu baixo a imagem ela mostra q ta corrompida) Quando Eu Entro No Site. Codígo:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs')
const app = express();

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(a,b) {return this.split(a).join(b)}

//app.use('/myspace', express.static(__dirname+'/myspace'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/windows94"))


app.get('/myspace/*', (req, res) => {
  request({uri: "http://myspace.windows93.net/" + req.originalUrl.split('/').slice(2).join('/')},function(er, rsp, body) {
    
    res.type(rsp.headers["content-type"]);
    res.send(body);
  console.log('A User Go To URL: ', req.originalUrl);
  });
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Comment: 1:Está usando o cloudinary, aws ou outro servidor? 2: O que você está usando para fazer o upload? Insomnia? 3: posta a forma que você está enviando, sabe que esse GET é só para receber dados né? 4: Pretende usar oq como front? se for para reactjs ou react-native te recomendo esse link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4e3WEv5drE&t=577s. 5:Qual banco de dados que você usa?

Comment: outro servidor, request, html

Comment: tente trocar o protocolo, de http, para https na uri do request: "https://myspace.win....